# add / apply custom databar to image in DigitalMicrograph GMS3

Tags: dm-script

I have an image that I want to apply a custom databar to via a script in DigitalMicrograph 3.21.1374.0.  I would also like to apply a custom layout (separate question here: [Apply Custom Layout to Image in DigitalMicrograph GMS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822112/apply-custom-layout-to-image-in-digitalmicrograph-gms3)).

The procedure that I currently do by hand is:

1. Right click on the image
2. Hover on layout (in context menu)
3. Left click "Add Databar"
4. Select the custom databar in dialog that pops up (the one I want is called "CheckDataBar")
5. Click OK

This works flawlessly - except that I would like to run a script to do it (so I can loop all the open images and apply the databar).

Here is the code that I have so far to do just one image:

```
//main - get front image and apply custom databar
image Img := GetFrontImage()
imageDisplay imgDisplay = Img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

ApplyDataBar(imgDisplay)//this only adds the scale bar not the custom databar that i would like
```

I have tried `ApplyDataBar(imgDisplay, CheckDataBar)` but that does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ApplyDatabar()` is an old command from earlier GMS versions and will only add the scalemarker.

However, [this answer to your other question ( applying layouts )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50824433/1302888) can also be used to apply the databar, provided the databar is part of the layout.

So, you have to create a *layout* which contains the custom databar first. Then you apply the *layout* to the *imageDocument* not the *imageDisplay*.

[image]
[image]

Comment: BmyGuest knows what they are talking about.  This was exactly what I needed.  Thanks! @BmyGuest