# Apply Custom Layout to Image in DigitalMicrograph GMS3

Tags: dm-script

I have an image in DigitalMicrograph GMS3 (v 3.21.1374.0) which i have applied a custom databar to (trying to learn how to do this via script here: [add / apply custom databar to image in DigitalMicrograph GMS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819924/add-apply-custom-databar-to-image-in-digitalmicrograph-gms3))

I have a custom layout that I can add manually by doing the following:

1. Right click on the image
2. Hover on layout (in context menu)
3. Left click "Apply Layout..."
4. Select the custom layout in dialog that pops up (the one I want is called "CheckLayout")
5. Click OK

How do I do this with a script?  I know how to get the image and the imagedisplay objects but that is as far as I get.

```
//main - get front image and apply custom layout
image Img := GetFrontImage()
imageDisplay imgDisplay = Img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)

//apply custom layout to image here
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout is a property of an *ImageDocument* not an image. The correct way of doing this (provided there exists a layout of name 'MyLayout') is:

```
ImageDocument doc = GetFrontImageDocument()
doc.ImageDocumentApplyLayout("MyLayout")
```

You might additionally be interested in the commands:

```
void ImageDocumentApplyLayout( ImageDocument, String )
void ImageDocumentRemoveDatabar( ImageDocument )
Number ImageDocumentGetLayoutCount( ImageDocument )
String ImageDocumentGetLayoutName( ImageDocument, Number )
```

as used in

```
ImageDocument doc = GetFrontImageDocument()
number nLO = doc.ImageDocumentGetLayoutCount()
Result( "\n Layouts in document:" +  nLO )
For( number i=0; i<nLO; i++)
{
    string layoutName = doc.ImageDocumentGetLayoutName(i)
    Result( "\n\t"+i+":"+layoutName)
}
```

Comment: Thanks again BmyGuest.  This worked well.  But I wanted to be able to apply it to a specific image not the front image so I modified the line to `ImageDocument doc = ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument( imgObject )` where imgObject is a reference object to the image I am modifying. @BmyGuest